# Solution for concurrent document changes by multiple nodejs processes?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, multiprocessing, crud

For a while I deal with this problem, but good solution I was not able to find. Imagine that there is a CRUD node application that communicates with cassandra cluster :)

For example the app has this routes:

```
curl -X POST 127.0.0.1:8080/characters -d '{"id":1, "name": "boba fett"}' 
curl -X PUT 127.0.0.1:8080/characters/1 -d '{"name": "Boba Fett"}' #<-- the problem 
curl -X GET 127.0.0.1:8080/characters/1 
curl -X DELETE 127.0.0.1:8080/characters/1
```

Now you should be able to run multiple nodejs processes with the same logic, but to prevent the possibility of changes to the same document in a database by two processes.

My ideas were:

- only one of the processes can modify the document
- each process gets a range of ids (for example, process a modifies the document with an even id, and process b modifies the document
  with an odd id)

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure these are the requirements for your app, then you can look into using Cassandra's lightweight transactions which allows you to control the behavior of `INSERT` and `UPDATE` using conditions.

This link should give you a quick intro: [Lightweight transactions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_ltwt_transaction_c.html).

Comment: I don't think it can be a solution.

Imagine a scenario that process **A** and process **B** updates the document **A1** at the same time `01.01.2016T00:00:00.000Z` . Process **C** reads the document **A1** one second after.


Q: What data gets the process **C**?      

1) Changes from process **A**;
2) Changes from process **B**;
3) Changes of the process, which is the last recorded data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a classical race condition. To resolve it Cassandra provides a timestamp for each mutation operation. Cassandra uses the timestamp to resolve which is the most recent data modification.

You can specify timestamps for mutation operations in CQL queries.

[A nice article about CQL timestamps and race condition](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/an-introduction-to-using-custom-timestamps-in-cql3/)